# Socket.io + Express: Express declaration error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

My requires:

```
//app.js Socket IO Test
var app = require('express').createServer(),
redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis'),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

My error:

```
Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server,
please use:
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
```

How do I modify my declarations to avoid this error?  I understand this methodology is now deprecated for Express, just not sure what it needs to be changed to...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nevermind, got the suggested code in the error working - wasn't at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace var app = require('express').createServer() with:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
```